# Getting error while indexing a spark Dataset<Row> in Elasticsearch.

Tags: java, elasticsearch, apache-spark, indexing

**Here mergedCrunchAndLinkedIn is my dataset**

```
 JavaEsSpark.saveToEs(mergedCrunchAndLinkedIn.toJavaRDD(), "spark/docs1");
```

[image]

Comment: The answer is here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/write-es-error-with-spark-2-0-release/56967

Comment: @AshisParajuli can you post what error is coming, what version of spark, scala, elasticsearch you are using

Comment: [Solved with the linke provided by Val]  thanks guys

Comment: can you vote up my question @Anupam Jain  .. i am unable to post other questions due to 0 vote in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this problem will be resolved 
compile group: 'org.elasticsearch', name: 'elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11', version: '5.0.0-beta1'